# Adding Orcid badge to a paper

Tags: latex3, acmart

I want to add the ORCID badge for the author of an article. I've copied the code exactly from this source: https://gugushvili.github.io/blog/2019/08/09/orcid

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,hyperref}
\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orcidicon}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) 
    circle [radius=0.16] 
    node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
    \draw[white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) 
    circle [radius=0.007];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}
\foreach \x in {A, ..., Z}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname orcid\x\endcsname{
        \noexpand\href{
            https://orcid.org/\csname orcidauthor\x\endcsname
            }
        {\noexpand\orcidicon}
    }
}
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0001-5446-5645}
\begin{document}
\title{OrcidProblem}
\author[Mickey Mouse]{Mickey Mouse\orcidA{}}
\authornote{lead author}
\affiliation{
  \institution{StackExchange}
}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

However, I get syntax errors:

- "Undefined control" at line 24, i.e. `\begin{document}`
- "Use of `\begin` doesn't match its definition" at line 31, i.e. `\maketitle` These
  errors can be ignored perhaps, but I'm also getting junk output in
  the result PDF of this form:

```
[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) circle [radius=0.16] node[white] ID; [white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) circle [radius=0.007];tikzpicture[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) circle [radius=0.16] node[white] ID; [white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) circle [ra-dius=0.007]; tikzpicture
```

I'm using Overleaf.

Comment: Hi Phasmid and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You haven't copied the code *exactly*. The example by Shota Gugushvili uses the `amsart` document class, you, however, use the `acmart` class which is entirely different. I didn't took the time to solve the issue but I can say that the class you are using greatly redefines the `\author` command which is the culprit of the errors. Shota's example works fine.

Comment: Since I'm required (I think) to use the acmart class, it sounds like I just won't be able to include the ORCID ids this way. Thanks for the answer.